# How do I connect to a PC in Remote Desktop using a different account than the one I'm logged in as?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

[image: VM screenshot]

This is for school and these are the VMs I'm provided with. The instructions on my assignment say after I enter the IP address for Client 1, there should be a, "More Choices" option under the General tab where I am to then select "Use a different account."

I can't find this option, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Once you provide an IP address (or computer address) you can enter the user name in the space provided. That works here on my own VMs.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately in my situation, the "User name" box below the IP address is grayed (can't select and change).

Comment: Is that maybe the only account on the VM? That is a possibility.

Comment: No, I created another account to use and under CLIENT1\Student, I went to control panel and went to "Select Users that can remotely access this PC" and added the account I want remotely connect to (the assignment directions previously called for this).

Comment: If you are using an `.rdp` file, see if it has a line containing `UserName:s:` with the shown user-name.

Comment: I'm not using an rdp file, would it work if I created one?